# Adding a footer with PDFsharp when concatenating pages

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, pdfsharp, migradoc

I merge PDF documents as shown here: [Concatenate Documents (PDFsharp)](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/ConcatenateDocuments-sample.ashx)
This example uses PDFsharp to merge the documents. I want to add a footer to each page. I can do this with `XGraphics.FromPdfPage()`, but it looks extremely complicated as the footer I need is complex (it consists of a table with different formats and styles). I would prefer to render it with MigraDoc's `Document` instead of PDFsharp's `PdfDocument` and `XGraphics`, as it looks much easier to do. Can I do that?

I looked at [Mix MigraDoc and PDFsharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/MixMigraDocAndPdfSharp-sample.ashx) but it doesn't look like what I seek. In the example they render MigraDoc over PDFsharp, but I think I need it vice versa.

If `XGraphics` is the only solution, is there anyway I could zoom the page I'm adding? It will overlap with the footer if I add it as it is - as the page fills whole space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Two pages on one](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/TwoPagesOnOne-sample.ashx) sample shows how you can import pages at a reduced size.

You can use MigraDoc to create pages with just the footers. Open this PDF file with PDFsharp to import the pages from the source files and draw them above the footer.

Comment: Could you please provide code example of "opening PDF file with PDFSharp and importing the pages from the source with drawing them above content?" I thought PDFSharp cannot modify documents

Comment: @Archeg The Watermark sample shows how to modify PDF files: http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Watermark-sample.ashx  The complete sample code is included with the source code package, available on CodePlex and SourceForge.